# Rpm repo for java on centos 6

Tags: centos, tomcat, java, centos6, maven

Is there any other repo from jpackage available for centos 6?

I don't like to build tomcat, maven from sources.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [How to install Tomcat 6 on RHEL 6 or CentOS 6](http://newpush.com/2011/10/how-to-install-tomcat-6-on-rhel-6-or-centos-6/)

There are available repositories indeed according to this KB: EPEL and RPMFORGE